# The Arduino copy of example code for tone() function produces a compile error: 'tone' is not declared in this scope. How can I fix this?

Tags: compile, error

It's 32-bit ARM core processor is SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU.

Error:

```
sketch_nov16b\sketch_nov16b.ino: In function 'void setup()': sketch_nov16b:49:43: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration); 
^ sketch_nov16b:61:13: error: 'noTone' was not declared in this scope noTone(8); 
^ exit status 1 'tone' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```cpp
/*

  Melody

  Plays a melody

  circuit:

  - 8 ohm speaker on digital pin 8

  created 21 Jan 2010

  modified 30 Aug 2011

  by Tom Igoe

  This example code is in the public domain.

  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Tone

*/

#include "pitches.h"

// notes in the melody:
int melody[] = {

  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {

  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

void setup() {

  // iterate over the notes of the melody:

  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second divided by the note type.

    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.

    int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[thisNote];

    tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.

    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:

    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;

    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);

    // stop the tone playing:

    noTone(8);

  }
}

void loop() {

  // no need to repeat the melody.
}
```

Comment: What core are you using?

Comment: It's 32-bit ARM core processor is SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU

Comment: Does this meet jsotola's request?sketch_nov16b\sketch_nov16b.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_nov16b:49:43: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope
     tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);
                                           ^
sketch_nov16b:61:13: error: 'noTone' was not declared in this scope
     noTone(8);
             ^
exit status 1
'tone' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @JohnB I said `do not paste into a comment` and you pasted into a comment ... this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site ... all info must be contained in the question

Answer (score 3):

In short, they just never implemented `tone()` in the Due/SAM core.
So you're not going to get the normal `tone()` function working.

- The tone.h [header is empty](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/blob/790ff2c852bf159787a9966bddee4d9f55352d15/cores/arduino/Tone.h).
  They probably should done any number of things that would produced a somewhat clearer warning about this.
- The counterpart .cpp file has been renamed to .cpp.disabled so that the no attempt is made to compile it and is [full of AVR-based code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/blob/790ff2c852bf159787a9966bddee4d9f55352d15/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp.disabled) that they'd copied into the project for reference with the intention of replacing it but never did.

There a [github issue](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/issues/24) tracking this. But it hasn't been updated since 2020. That issue [references the Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-due-and-tone/133302) for apparently working alternative code for producing tones. So maybe try their code.

I don't see any popular alternative packaged as an Arduino library for producing simple tones. However, the chip has a DAC and there is an [Audio Library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Audio/tree/master). It's a bit overkill for producing basic tones, but you could modify [the example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Audio/blob/master/examples/SimpleAudioPlayer/SimpleAudioPlayer.ino) there to fill the buffer with a tone's waveform rather than loading it from an sdcard file.